# How can I make a link in HTML that opens in the Google Drive app on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, google-drive-api

I am trying to find a way to open a link on a site from the website on the iPad with the google drive app and not in the browser window. I am new to HTML and want to know what code/string to add as opposed to what I currently have.

example:

```
<a href="https://drive.google.com/"><input name="Dashboard" type="button" value="Click here to access Google Drive"
```

Thanks in advance!

---

I am referencing the link on our website using wikis,but it can be edited in html. So the users will be clicking on this lonk in the browser in safari on the iPad and I'd like it to open with the google drive app already installed and not google drive in the browser window.

Comment: Please use a _relevant_ question title.

Comment: Oops, told you i was new...lol! Thanks for changing the title for me :)